# R.Net 1.9.0 does not work with .Net 5 Core application

Tags: c#, r, .net, r.net

Below logic working fine with .Net Framework 4.7.1 and its not working with .Net 5 application. Application simply crashed without displaying any error message.

Help me to run R.Net in .Net 5 application without any error.

```
class Program
{
    public static string RPath { get; set; } = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin\x64";
    public static string RHome { get; set; } = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(RPath, RHome);
        REngine _rEngine = REngine.GetInstance();
        Console.WriteLine("Object created");
    }
}
```

Referring R.Net package from Nuget
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't get any error messages, the best place to look for is the system event log. A typical problem is a missing dll in the working directory.

Comment: .NET 5 and 6 are .NET *Core* 5 and 6, not a new version of .NET Framework. The final version of .NET Framework was 4.8.